# Do you have to make a touch attack to heal an ally?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, touch-attacks, healing

### Question

The *[cure wounds](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/cureLightWounds.htm)* spells, and most [healing](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#healing) [spells](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#spell), have a [range](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#range) of [touch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#touchSpellsinCombat) and a target of creature touched. Do you have to actually succeed on a touch [attack roll](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#attackRoll) to heal an ally?

### Reason for Concern

We have come across this issue and have no idea what the solution is. We lost our healer and now the [bard](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/bard.htm) is our primary healer. The original healer was a [wererat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm#wererat) with a high Str and made even higher when he went into [rat form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/direRat.htm) thus making it easy to make a touch attack, so it was never an issue before.

But the bard is based primarily in Dex and has a Str mod of −2, so it has now become a real issue to heal party members. The bard had healing spells the whole time but only **needed** to heal outside of battle (because to heal in battle bard must stop [their songs](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/bard.htm#bardicMusic) and lose a point from their songs a day).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you do not have to make an attack roll for healing your allies.

If the target is willing to accept the healing spell, there is no attack roll required.

[Touch Spells in Combat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#touchSpellsinCombat)

> You can automatically touch one friend or use the spell on yourself, but to touch an opponent, you must succeed on an attack roll.

---

If the bard is really worried about burning through his Bardic Music uses per day, then consider the feats Extra Music, Melodic Casting, and/or Lingering Song.

- Extra Music gives him extra [Bardic Music](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/bard.htm#bardicMusic) uses per day.
- Melodic Casting allows him to cast spells while maintaining a bard song
- Lingering Song allows his songs to stay in effect for an additional 5
  rounds after he quits playing.

Another combination I have always loved...

1. Get the feat Obtain Familiar, and get yourself a raven
   [familiar](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard.htm#familiars). [Raven](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/raven.htm) familiars can speak one
   language<sup>1</sup>.
2. Since familiars are able to use the skills you have, and Bards have
   [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/useMagicDevice.htm) as a class skill, your familiar could use that
   skill as well.
3. The familiar could carry a [Wand](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wands.htm) of [Cure Light Wounds](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/cureLightWounds.htm), activate
   the [trigger](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#spellTrigger) since it can speak, and touch all of your allies
   (healing them) without ever having the bard stop singing.

---

<sup>1</sup>A raven familiar can speak one language of its master’s choice as a [supernatural ability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#supernaturalAbilities).

Comment: for #2, even if it would not be a class skill, as long as you have 1 rank in it (2x cross class) the raven can benefit from those skills too. choosing Common is pretty much the best option for lots of options.